# Providing external routines from a C library in a threadsafe manner

Tags: c, linker, fortran, global, ffi

I have a c-library wrapped around a fortran library that I want to use in OCaml. The obvious solution is to map the c-interface into ocaml routines using some handwritten code to deal with GC.

However, it turns out that the algorithm implemented by the fortran library gets its inputs as EXTERNAL routines, i.e.:

```
EXTERNAL         RHS
```

This means that the input is essentially passed by the linker. The C-wrapper has a nice interface collecting all required input in a struct, but essentially provides one global instance of that struct and then defines all the missing external routines in terms of that global instance.

As a functional programmer, this smells like an antipattern to me. Since I do not want to rewrite the fortran code, my question is:

- Is there a safe, idiomatic way to link the fortran library and avoiding global state clashups? Can the C-library provide the global state of the fortran library, without rewriting the fortran code?
- If no such way exists, what is a good C11 (i.e. OS independent) idiom to protect the global state? I'd need a kind of global lock that only allows access through a key that is issued exactly once.
- I just read about thread local declarations in C11, would that be an option?

Comment: The last bullet point is just a mutex. Every multitasking OS has them. If your OS is POSIX compliant, look for `pthread_mutex_lock` and friends.

Comment: Of course, but I'd rather avoid an operating system dependency on that level. The library will probably be used under windows as well. So I guess there I need some kind of #ifdef snippet that does this correctly.

Comment: It is quite likely, that rewriting the Fortran routine to accept a function pointer would be MUCH shorter, then inventing a kludge around it.

Comment: `EXTERNAL` on its own doesn't necessarily equate to global state/"linker provided input".  If the name in the external statement is also a dummy argument, then it is passed in, just like any other procedure argument.  (If it is not already a dummy argument, then making it one as per Vladimir's suggestion is probably relatively straightforward.)  `COMMON` on the other hand, is a different matter, and is the more usual cause of global state.